# Hellowired Navigation Bar?[SOLVED]

Tags: magento-1.8, template, ce-1.9.1.0

So i us this Template called hellowired. everything works fine. 
But my navigation bar is showing nothing can anyone please help

[my site](http://www.ittd.nl/Magento/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert since I'm in the process of figuring out Magento myself, but did you at least create some categories in the backend?

You could compare the home.phtml template file to check the part that calls the main navigation. There might be an type error calling the menu part in the hellowired theme you are using.

```
<?=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.menu')->toHtml()?>
```

Comment: Yes i found this {<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>} which lead me to this {<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu"/>} and then i have no clu

Comment: Does the menu show up when you set the template back to default?

Comment: I just fixed it with some off your help thanks